# cvxpy DPP Doesn't Work For Complex Parameter

Tags: python, cvxpy

I need to solve a large number of small convex optimisation problems with the same constraints, so I am trying to use cvxpy's DPP feature to cache/speedup compilation. It doesn't seem to work for my problem containing a single complex matrix parameter `L`.

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

A = np.eye(4)+np.eye(4)*1j
L = cp.Parameter((4,4),complex=True)
X = cp.Variable((4,4),hermitian=True)
obj = cp.Minimize(cp.norm(X-L,'fro'))
prob = cp.Problem(obj)
L.value = A
assert prob.is_dcp(dpp=True)
prob.solve(solver=cp.SCS,verbose=True)
```

If I change the definitions of `A` and `L` to `A=np.eye(4)` and `L = cp.Parameter((4,4))`, then I do see the `(Subsequent compilations of this problem, using the same arguments, should take less time.)` message in the verbose print out.

I am using cvxpy version 1.2.1.

Does anyone know what's going on? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you be more precise regarding "It doesn't seem to work"? I ran your code without any issue. I use cvxpy 1.1.0.

Comment: I am expecting to see the (Subsequent compilations of this problem, using the same arguments, should take less time.) message in the verbose log, which I do not see with complex L.

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/cvxpy/cvxpy/issues/1666 then

Comment: Yes, precisely. Thanks Michal!